# Binary Search Tree Question about root deletion

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

So, I recently got to know what binary search trees are, but I have one question. How do you delete a root of a binary search tree if it already has a right and a left? And those right and left, have their own respective right and left sides? I'm still not sure how to do this, can someone help me

Comment: You can google ```bst delete node```

Comment: Please learn that you’re supposed to search before posting a question here, and in your question account for what you found and in what way it was insufficient for answering your question. As @zysaaa seems to indicate, in this case you would likely have found your answer easily. There’s no need waiting around for hours for us to find it for you.